# Does every tame Deligne-Mumford stack over a perfect field have a dense substack which is smooth?

Tags: algebraic-stacks

Does every tame Deligne-Mumford stack over a perfect field have a open substack which is smooth ? If we assume the stack is reduced ?

Comment: Is the field perfect?  That is already false for reduced, finite type $k$-schemes if $k$ is not perfect.

Comment: Sorry, assume the base field is perfect.

Comment: Presumably your stack is meant to be (at least locally) of finite type over that perfect field (not just "over a [perfect] field"). Any Artin stack has a smooth cover by a scheme, so by the very *definition* of smoothness for Artin stacks (and its well-posedness) the fact that reduced locally finite type schemes over a perfect field have dense Zariski-open smooth locus instantly implies the same for reduced Artin stacks locally of finite type over a perfect field (without any need for the tameness condition in the DM case).

Answer (score 2):

As nfdc23 writes in his comment, the answer is positive (and follows instantly from the corresponding fact for  finite type schemes over a perfect field). More precisely:

Let $k$ be a perfect field and let $X$ be a reduced  finite type algebraic stack over $k$. Let $P\to X$ be a smooth surjective  morphism with $P$ a scheme of  finite type over $k$. As $P\to X$ is smooth, it follows that $P$ is reduced. Therefore, $P$ is generically smooth over $k$, i.e., there is a dense open $U\subset P$ such that $U$ is smooth over $k$. (Here we use perfectness of $k$.)

Now, as the morphism $U\to X$ is smooth and $U$ is smooth over $k$, it follows that its image (which is a dense open substack of $X$) is smooth over $k$.